# Easy-to-do experiments that clearly show outstanding properties of graphene

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment, carbon-allotropes

By chance, we received some monolayer [graphene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene) sheets (20 cm x 20 cm) and mixed coper-graphene wires for free at our university. I would like to prepare some very-easy-to-do experiments for the chemistry students that show the awesome properties of graphene, and which could be carried out with very simple lab equipment or even home experiments. What are some good experiments we could do?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to post this in the Physics forum, as many of the outstanding properties of graphene are expected to be physical.  See this Periodic Video: [Graphene](http://www.periodicvideos.com/videos/mv_graphene.htm)

Given this, two things to try.  First, graphene should conduct electricity, like graphite but not like carbon.  Second, graphene may dissolve in nonpolar solvents like carbon tetrachloride, similar to buckyballs, to produce colorful solutions.  See this Periodic Video: [BuckyBall](http://www.periodicvideos.com/videos/mv_buckyball.htm)

Both these experiments should be checked in advance: I'm extrapolating from other experiments, but have not done these myself.

Comment: Are you sure that a 20xmX20cm intact film will dissolve? Buckyball is molecular material, graphene is like a polymer: one big thing interconnected with covalent bonds. And why would it be colorful?  Free standing nanotubes and buckyballs can have color. Dissolution only helps separate the coagulates, so show you the color of the freestanding molecules. Graphene has no problem like this as far as I know.